# How to optimize primitives in SecondLife/Opensim?

Tags: models, triangulation

SecondLife/Opensim uses Primitives to construct models. How it works in details is explained [here](http://www.realityprime.com/articles/how-sl-primitives-really-work).

Now I have many triangles which link together. Is there any way to make them into one prim, thus reducing the number of prims?

Answer (score 1):

No. A "prim" is a primative object, and is the base building blocks for building 3d content.

You cannot combine shapes into a single prim.

However you can use prims efficiently by using clever textures instead of details, or by using fewer larger prims to create your objects.

Comment: The point of a prim, in SecondLife, is that it requires a very small amount of data to fully define a (potentially) very complicated model.  The purpose of modelling with prims is specifically to discourage people from modelling things using triangle soups, which require a lot more data to store and to transfer to each viewer.

Comment: @AttackingHobo: Then how should I use fewer larger prims to replace my triangular soups?

Comment: Build your objects with larger prims, and use textures to add details.